# SwiftUI - Value of protocol type 'Any' cannot conform to 'View'

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to convert an array of SwiftUI views into a PDF. I think I just about have it, except for one small problem - the array type. I can't get the views into an array that PDFKit will recognize. In the code below, if I replace

```
let tempView = UIHostingController(rootView: view)
```

with

```
let tempView = UIHostingController(rootView: PageOne())
```

the code below works great. But when I try to put PageOne() into an array of type `Any` I get the error, `"Value of protocol type 'Any' cannot conform to 'View'; only struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols"` Which makes sense. But what I don't get is how I should be doing it.

```
var viewsToConvert = [Any]()
viewsToConvert.append(PageOne())
viewsToConvert.append(PageTwo())

let pdfData = NSMutableData()
let pdfPageFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height)
UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, pdfPageFrame, nil)
let graphicsContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
for view in viewsToConvert {
   let tempView = UIHostingController(rootView: view)
   tempView.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height)
            
   UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage()
   tempView.view.layer.render(in: graphicsContext!)
            
   tempView.removeFromParent()
   tempView.view.removeFromSuperview()
}
UIGraphicsEndPDFContext()

return saveViewPdf(data: pdfData, fileName: "Quote")
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `AnyView` instead of `Any`:

```
var viewsToConvert = [AnyView]()
viewsToConvert.append(AnyView(PageOne()))
viewsToConvert.append(AnyView(PageTwo()))
```

Comment: It worked! I'm curious though - I tried to cast my views to AnyView using (PageOne() as! AnyView) and the app crashed. What is the difference?

Comment: @squarehippo10 That's because [AnyView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/anyview) is just another `View` and `PageOne` does not conform to `AnyView` (but to View).